# How to open a file in a specific application using ubuntu terminal

Tags: command-line-interface

I have tried xdg-open, but the problem is that it is opening the file in the defaut application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `xdg-open` manual

> xdg-open opens a file or URL in the user's preferred application. If a
>   URL is provided the URL will be opened in the user's preferred web
>   browser. If a file is provided the file will be opened in the
>   preferred application for files of that type. xdg-open supports file,
>   ftp, http and https URLs.
>
> xdg-open is for use inside a desktop session only. It is not
>   recommended to use xdg-open as root.

So you have two solutions

1. Change the preferred application from settings
2. Use the program you want to open the file with

For example, if I would like to open `foo.txt` using `vim`, I just type

```
vim foo.txt
```